# Error while compiling in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, internet-explorer

I'm building an IE extension (ATL) with VS2008 and somehow when I switch to release mode it gives me some linking error:

```
Error   2   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImplAddon.h': No such file or directory   *************** 19  Engine
Error   3   fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\release addon\engine.lib'   Addon Addon
```

I've tried to add to each of the projects in the "Additional include directories" in the project's properties the relevant path to 'ImplAddon.h' but nothing helps.

Any idea what to do??

Thanks a lot fellas :)

Comment: are you sure that you have added dditional include directories both to release and debug configuration?

Comment: does your project compiled fine in debug mode?

Comment: yes it does compile fine in debug. I've noticed that you need to add the additional directories in release mode but that's not helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click each project and go to `properties` then top,left there is a drop-down to select the environmental. select `all configurations` there. then go to `C++`-> `General` -> `Additional directories` then add the paths of your header fails located at.

[image]